# Reboot to a specific distro from ssh

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbmc, retropie

I do have Raspbian (+ retropie) and Raspbmc running in my raspberry pi. I do loads of admin from work via ssh but I can only reboot to the current distro. Is there any command/config I can select which distro I want the next reboot to start from?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Which image are using? Did you installed Raspbmc and Raspbian from NOOBs image?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NOOBs image, you could edit the `autoboot.txt` file located in the FAT partition, but keep in mind that will deactivate the GUI Boot Screen.

You only have to add `boot_partition=<partition number of your OS>` to that autoboot.txt and save it.

Here is completely explained:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs#how-to-bypass-the-recovery-splashscreen-and-boot-directly-into-a-fixed-partition